# Registering Custom Libraries in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

In this article, it is shown how to use SendGrid in Windows Azure Mobile Services:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/send-email-with-sendgrid/

The interesting part is, how a developer can call `new SendGrid('**username**', '**password**');` from within a server side script to start using the SendGrid API.

For me it looks like a custom script has been registered on the server when I choose the SendGrid add-on.

How could I register a script of my own? I tried googling around but searches such as register custom script only returned tutorials on how to write server side scripts, not how to register a custom library to be used on those scripts.

**In short:**

1. What are the basic steps to accomplish this
2. Is there instructions for this somewhere
3. Can you suggest an alternative method to accomplish the same functionality (ie. requireJS and hosting your custom script in a CDN maybe?)

Comment: Great question! I'd guess they just omitted the package installation process in their tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach to using custom scripts with Mobile Services is this:

1. Enable source control for your Windows Azure Mobile service.
2. Install Git on your local machine.
3. Use Git to deploy custom scripts (or node modules) from your local machine to your Windows Azure Mobile service.

There is more detail here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/store-scripts-in-source-control/